# Python 3.3: Obtaining multiple lines of input, then calculating them separately

Tags: python, python-3.3, multiline

I am very new to Python and I am trying to create a program that will calculate the distance between two X and Y coordinates given by the user, separated by a space. I was able to do it for a single line, but I want the user to be able to enter multiple lines of different coordinates and then stop when they enter "0 0 0 0". I then want to calculate each distance and tell the user whether or not the distance is less than 100.

Sample input:
(x1 y1 x2 y2)

```
124.45 445.35 65.34 530.45
124.45 445.35 74.34 530.45  
0 0 0 0
```

Sample output:

```
Greater than 100
Less than 100
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#Obtain input from user
text = input()
while True:
    x1 y1, x2, y2=input().split()
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = [float(x1), float(y1), float(x2), float(y2)]
    if text == "0 0 0 0":
        break
    else:
        #Calculate distance
        import math
        distance = math.sqrt((y1 - y2)**2 + (x1- x2)**2)
        if distance >= 100:
            print("Greater than 100")
        else:
            print("Less than 100")
```

My problem is that after 2 lines of input, it gives me an answer. It does not continue until I input 0 0 0 0. It also only gives me the answer for the first input, not all.

Comment: You are checking against the variable `text`, but assigning to `line`.

Comment: I would discourage you from using something like all-zero values or the string `quit` as a sentinel. Instead, read until you get an End Of File condition (in Python 3, `EOFError` will be raised).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

`while True: # create an endless loop
  text=input()
  if text == "0 0 0 0":#your exit strategy from an endless loop
    break
  print(text) #Do whatever you want with you input, calculate & give your feedback
print("exiting") #we are done`

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem of allowing 0 0 0 0 to stop the input lines, but now I've hit another issue!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful now... you are reading data from the user twice!

once to assign the input to the text variable (but this is outside the loop, so it happens only once, and it is never splitted or otherwise manipulated)

and one more time in the loop, which is splitted on the fly, but never checked for its "exit command"...

you should move your assignment to the "text" variable inside the loop, and do the splitting on it :)

Answer (score 0):

While you already have an answer, there is an alternative way to receive an unknown amount of input lines from the user. The answer you accepted does not allow you to use previous inputs as it overwrites the data (ex: calculate the area of region bounded by an unknown amount of input coordinates, could be a triangle, as square etc). You risk writing spaghetti code in doing so.

To do this, create a list before you start asking for inputs, and then `append` each input to the list. Iterate over the list and process data:

```
inputs = []
get_input = True
while get_input:
    text = input("Enter data")  # or whatever you use
    if text != "0 0 0 0":  # exit condition
        inputs.append(text)  # add to list
    else:
        get_input = False  # break loop

for input in inputs:
    process_inputs()  # do stuff with each input
```

Comment: Ah sorry! I made a slight mistake on the conditions, the loop should be `while get_input`. I don't know how I missed that, thanks for pointing it out! I just tested it in python 3.4, should work now!

Comment: That seems like rather a different problem. Here, we know that there will always be four coordinates per set of data; making a list with the entirety of the input just feels wasteful to me.

Comment: You are not wrong, it's simply a different approach. I personally save inputs and such because memory is cheap and I often find I want it later, so I just put in the 2 extra lines. Hence my suggestion. No it's not entirely necessary for this _exact_ situation, but I felt like helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you not to use a sentinel value as it breaks the second part of the Unix philosophy *(play nice with others using text streams).* Instead, read until you get an end-of-file condition. In Python, trying to read past the end of the file will raise an `EOFError`. In this case, though, you can simply iterate over the file—you'll get one line each iteration (with a trailing linebreak), and it will stop automatically at the end of the file:

```
import math
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = (float(token) for token in line.split())
    distance = math.sqrt((y1 - y2) ** 2 + (x1 - x2) ** 2)
    if distance >= 100:
        print("Greater than or equal to 100")
    else:
        print("Less than 100")
```

You should also put all your `import`s at the top of the file, separated from other things by an empty line, and leave whitespace around infix operators (like I have). These and other guidelines can be found in the [official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which I would also strongly encourage you to read.